# Verify pkcs7 Signature received from AS2 trading partner

Tags: c#, digital-signature, x509certificate, pkcs#7

I am receiving an AS2 message from my trading partner. I have successfully decrypted it and it has following content:

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; boundary="----1E2FB76A361B53C9D12B3971C32BC0D8"; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256"

------1E2FB76A361B53C9D12B3971C32BC0D8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="edi.dat"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset="ascii"; name="edi.dat"

ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*SPSAS2         *ZZ*SPSAS2         *140919*1159*|*00501*100000001*0*P*>
GS*PO*AS2S3REC*AS2S3SEND*20140919*1159*123*X*005010
ST*850*1234
BEG*00*SA*SPSAS2TEST**20121017
REF*IA*TEST
PER*OC*Someone*TE*2844994944
DTM*001*20121025
N1*ST*SomeoneElse
N3*My address is private
N4*ST THOMAS*VI*00801
PO1*54812*1*EA***SK*123546*VP*123546*UP*123456987111
CTT*1
SE*11*1234
GE*1*123
IEA*1*100000001

------1E2FB76A361B53C9D12B3971C32BC0D8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
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------1E2FB76A361B53C9D12B3971C32BC0D8--
```

It has the signature in "Base64" format and "pkcs7-signature". I am not able to match signature. I am considering following part as main data:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*SPSAS2         *ZZ*SPSAS2         *140919*1159*|*00501*100000001*0*P*>
GS*PO*AS2S3REC*AS2S3SEND*20140919*1159*123*X*005010
ST*850*1234
BEG*00*SA*SPSAS2TEST**20121017
REF*IA*TEST
PER*OC*Someone*TE*2844994944
DTM*001*20121025
N1*ST*SomeoneElse
N3*My address is private
N4*ST THOMAS*VI*00801
PO1*54812*1*EA***SK*123546*VP*123546*UP*123456987111
CTT*1
SE*11*1234
GE*1*123
IEA*1*100000001
```

and base64 string as sign. and sung following function to match sign:

```
static bool Verify(string text, byte[] signature, string certPath)
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath);
            RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
            SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
            UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
            // Verify the signature with the hash
            return csp.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature);
        }
```

But this function is not matching the signature.
Please help me with this problem.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

I can't, personally, get the data to validate.  (I'm assuming that either there are trailing spaces that aren't copying correctly or that the payload has been altered (e.g. "My address is private"))

The flow that I expect is happening:

- The pkcs7 content is a CMS SignedData with detached content.
- The signed content was specified in the first stream

So you need to do something like:

```
byte[] dataBytes = ReadFirstSegment();
byte[] signatureBytes = ReadSecondSegment();

SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(dataBytes), detached: true);
cms.Decode(signatureBytes);
// This next line throws a CryptographicException if the signature can't be verified
cms.CheckSignature(true);

SignerInfoCollection signers = cms.SignerInfos;

if (signers.Count != 1)
{
    // probably fail
}

if (!IsExpectedCertificate(signers[0].Certificate))
{
    // fail
}

// success
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more about



`ReadFirstSegment(); ReadSecondSegment();`